# Unmap TT files in VS.NET 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, t4

Is there a way to unmap .tt files in Studio?

Every time I create or edit one, it warns me about executing them, then creates a .cs file for it.

The thing is my .tt files are something completely different. They're Template Toolkit files from Perl project, and their standard extension is .tt

I've tried adding an extension map from tt to the text editor, but I still get the unwanted behavior  in this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning can be fixed in Tools->Options, "Text Templating".

I don't believe it's possible to keep the "mapping" from happening, but it is possible to undo it. With one of the .tt files selected, press F4 to see the Properties grid. You'll see that the "Custom tool" property is set to "TextTemplatingFileGenerator". Clear that field, and you'll find that the .cs file goes away.